# Custom feeds plugin not discovered

Tags: 8, feeds, plugins

I am trying to create/work on an Address target plugin for the Feeds module. I have tried applying [this Address target patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/Add_a_address_field_feeds_target_.patch) (shown below) from [this related issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/address/issues/2882589). However, the Address field on the content type to which I am mapping feed sources does not appear as a target. I did try clearing the cache.

However, when I move this code, which attempts to create an Address field Feeds target, to the Feeds module, changing the namespace appropriately and placing it in `feeds/src/Feeds/Target/Address.php`, the Address field *does* appear as a target.

Question: Why is the patch below, written in the same style and using the same techniques as the other Feeds target plugins, not being discovered, even though the annotation seems to be correct to result in discovery? (Particularly given that it *is* discovered when it's patched into the Feeds module.)

Possibly relevant is: What changes in annotation discovery when a module is looking in other namespaces? I would think it should be discovered using AnnotatedClassDiscovery as defined in the [D8 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/d8-plugin-discovery), since it seems to have the appropriate annotation.

Edit: In case it's relevant, I have also tried removing both the `prepareValue` and `prepareValues` functions from the target class, per the Feeds maintainer's comments on the linked issue.

Here's the patch in question:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\address\Feeds\Target;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\feeds\FieldTargetDefinition;
use Drupal\feeds\Exception\EmptyFeedException;
use Drupal\feeds\Exception\TargetValidationException;
use Drupal\feeds\Plugin\Type\Target\FieldTargetBase;

/**  
 * Defines a address field mapper.  
 *  
 * @FeedsTarget(  
 *   id = "address_feeds_target",  
 *   field_types = {"address"}  
 * )  
 */ 
class Address extends FieldTargetBase {

  /**    
   * {@inheritdoc}    
   */   
  protected static function prepareTarget(FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return FieldTargetDefinition::createFromFieldDefinition($field_definition)
      ->addProperty('langcode')
      ->addProperty('country_code')
      ->addProperty('administrative_area')
      ->addProperty('locality')
      ->addProperty('dependent_locality')
      ->addProperty('postal_code')
      ->addProperty('sorting_code')
      ->addProperty('address_line1')
      ->addProperty('address_line2')
      ->addProperty('organization')
      ->addProperty('given_name')
      ->addProperty('additional_name')
      ->addProperty('family_name');   
  }

}
```

Comment: It's likely a problem in your code.

Comment: @Jaypan Can you clarify why you say that? Given that it works in the context of the Feeds module, but doesn't work when outside that context, I would think it would be _unlikely_ to be the patch that I applied, which I assume is what you're referring to.

Comment: I say that because your code isn’t working. Drupal does not discriminate - If code is written correctly Drupal will pick it up.

Comment: Ok, sure that's fair and I agree. I think that I knew that though.... The problem is that clearly the code works in _some_ context. So my question is why it stops working when in the Address module, even though many examples illustrate using that principle for implementing plugins. I guess I thought you were commenting based on some specific understanding of the scenario. I'll clarify my question further to account for my understanding that it's not Drupal's fault...

Comment: Have you cleaned the registry after adding this?

Comment: Are you referring to the site cache when you say registry? I cleared all the caches, made sure no database updates are pending, made sure cron has run.

Comment: Should've worked, is the address module enabled?

Comment: Yeah, the Address module is enabled and there is an Address field on the content type I'm attempting to map. I've tried this on multiple sites as well.

Comment: I will try this patch in a few hours and let u know how it goes.

Comment: Worked fine for me... Could be possible that you have 2 address modules in /modules somewhere. Perhaps accidentally moved inside another module? or perhaps even one in /core/modules. You could do a quick test and delete the address module folder, if you don't see any missing module errors, then indeed there is another address module folder somewhere.

Comment: Oh, wow... I cannot believe that was it. modules/address and modules/contrib/address... Thank you so much. I've never had that happen before nor do I know how that happened, but it did.